# How to reset default top bar style

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, top-bar

Today I was tinkering my Ubuntu 21.10. Looking for a way to configure my top panel, I installed the extensions [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) and [Shell Configurator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4254/shell-configurator/). All was fine until I removed Unite after realizing that it doesn't do what want to do — my top bar became too large.

[image]

I can still control the size with Shell Configurator but now if I turn it off the gigantic top bar appears again. I believe Unite might have made some modification to configuration files and want to know where the files are so I can reset my default top panel style.
Thanks!

Edit: While I can control the top panel size with Shell Configurator, the settings of Shell Configurator now seems to change randomly. E.g. if I set the top bar size to 55, and come back a while later, it becomes 66 or 90 or some other random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting as follows:

1. Open the Extensions tool and disable all extensions
2. Delete all local extensions - we actually move, so you can restore the previous state if you wish

   ```
   mv ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions_old`
   mkdir ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
   ```
3. Log out then back in
4. Enable extensions again, and reinstall the custom extensions you prefer.

To undo, turn all extensions off again, delete `extensions`  and rename the `extensions_old` directory back.

Comment: Hi! I edited your answer to improve the formatting. Although I fully agree that extensions may be a cause of this issue, I'd not prefer moving or removing them as Gnome may start misbehaving. On the other hand, I also think that the shell theme may be a cause of this issue, as the top bar is *fully* controlled by the shell theme. In my opinion, the question is unclear and needs clarity.

Comment: Thank you, I am not quite familiar with this indenting of the source code. You may be right in that the extensions may not be the issue here, but some additional custom shell theming that is being used. Anyway, we can await the reactions a bit. There is no issue or risk in *disabling* the extensions, then removing them as I advised, especially also when followed by a log out.

Comment: That seems to have reset the default style, so I think the problems were the extensions. Shell Configurator still gives random sizes though, so I'll maybe contact the developers there. Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: Of course! I'm new here so I didn't know that. Thanks for reminding me!